# vbscript script reset at error

Tags: vbscript

I have a problem which I cannot get fixed,
the solution tho is probably very simple for an expert to explain.
tho I haven't managed to get it working, even with the help of existing
posts on stackoverflow and some other scripting forums.

so my goal is to have my simple script (which i'm using as a presentation) to reset
itself at whatever error.
I already experimented with 'on error resume next', this however just made my computer
startup IE over and over again.

so again my goal is to get my script keep going after an error turns up.
if I am anoying anyone with my question please let me know and i'll change it or slab myself (depending on the situation).

my script:

Do
    'on error resume next'

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = 1
objIE.FullScreen=True
objIE.Navigate "About:Blank"



Do Until VarType(objIE) = 9
    WScript.Sleep 4000
    objIE.Navigate "local URL"

    WScript.Sleep 6000
    objIE.Navigate "local URL"

        WScript.Sleep 10000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"


        WScript.Sleep 8000
        objIE.Navigate "URL"

        WScript.Sleep 8000
        objIE.Navigate "URL"

                      WScript.Sleep 12000
        objIE.Navigate "URL"

        WScript.Sleep 10000
        objIE.Navigate "URL"

        WScript.Sleep 14000
        objIE.Navigate "URL"

            WScript.Sleep 14000
        objIE.Navigate "URL"


Loop
```

Loop

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `Do Until VarType(objIE) = 9`? In my setup the `VarType` of `objIE` is 8 (string), because `objIE` returns its name, `Windows Internet Explorer`, as default property. You can try it with `MsgBox objIE`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, what I'm sorry if I have done something unusual. i'm not quite an expert you see, '9' stands for internetexplorer 9 which would be the version of the application wouldt it? I thought the 'do until vartyp' line is to make the loop work.

Comment: While [there are ways to detect the IE version you are on](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/09/how-can-i-determine-which-version-of-internet-explorer-is-installed-on-a-computer.aspx), you don't need it for the loop to run. You start with `Do`, enter your statements in the following lines and close with a `Loop` (or `Loop While True` if you want to show your intentions). Now the loop will run forever.

Comment: this is exactely what its ment to do, its a presentation on a public screen in a guest room within my company's reception. for the same reason I need it to be able to keep running even tho there are errors that can occure.

Comment: If the OERN not help then please describe your problem with more details as the current description is unclear.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot get the script to work around error's or reset itstelf in case a error shows up. the script is ment to run 'forever'. possible a solution might be "on error" but since I can not get it working I'm asking for help..

Comment: EDIT: the reason why te script scrashes is because of reaching the maximum amount of threads every time, herefor it might also be possible to make a loopcounter and let it close the IE object and start it up again. this way there won't be the problem of memory running out.

Answer (score 0):

This script doesnt end, you must terminate the wscript process to stop it.
It checks all the running processes on the system for "iexplore"; if internet explorer is not found, the script starts a new instance.  If iexplore is found, it sends the navigate commands.

```
On Error Resume Next 

Do While true
If Check() = true Then
    WScript.Sleep 4000
    objIE.Navigate "local URL"

    WScript.Sleep 6000
    objIE.Navigate "local URL"

    WScript.Sleep 10000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"

    WScript.Sleep 8000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"

    WScript.Sleep 8000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"

    WScript.Sleep 12000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"

    WScript.Sleep 10000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"

    WScript.Sleep 14000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"

    WScript.Sleep 14000
    objIE.Navigate "URL"
End If
If Check() = false Then
    'Start Iexplore and direct it to blank page
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = 1
    objIE.FullScreen=True
    objIE.Navigate "About:Blank"
End If


Loop

'Check to see if IEXPLORE is running
Function Check()
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strList
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
    If (inStr(objProcess.Name, "iexplore")) then
        Check = true
    Else
        Check = false
    End If
Next
End Function
```